# On what factors does the distance a liquid travel from a hole in container depend?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

We know that [Toricelli's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law) tells us that liquids travels faster (& farther) from the bottom holes in a container.

My question :

if we take identical containers, make the hole at same point in all of the containers and fill them with different liquids (say water, kerosene and olive oil). Which of the liquids will go the maximum horizontal distance? Will they all go the same distance or will the more dense liquids land farther? Will viscosity play a part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you understand that Torricelli' Law only applies to [inviscid flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inviscid_flow#:%7E:text=Inviscid%20flow%20is%20the%20flow,many%20applications%20in%20fluid%20dynamics.)?

That is, such a flow, applies only to **idealized flow** of liquids of **zero viscosity**. In reality such liquids do not exist, of course.

In this idealization 'parcels' of mass $\mathrm{d}m$ of fluid are in *free fall*, according to Torricelli (and Bernoulli)(by conservation of kinetic ebnrgy):

$$\frac12 \mathrm{d}mv(h)^2=\mathrm{d}m gh$$

$$\Rightarrow\boxed{v(h)=\sqrt{2hg}}$$

> Which of the liquids will go the maximum horizontal distance?

You mean where will the horizontal difference take them? Wikipedia's entry for inviscid liquids [Torricelli's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law) shows that rather well.

Comment: I understand Toricelli's law to the extent that velocity depends only on the height of fluid column above the point of exit. However, my question is if the height is constant would different real life liquids exhibit same flow? What _other_ factors would make them behave differently from one another? On the horizontal distance, I wanted to know how far from container will they fall? If you could quote the relevant portion from Wikipedia that would be helpful because I can't seem to infer it.

Comment: The horizontal outflow velocity depends on the viscosity in a *complex way*.  Different *real life* liquids will behave differently (e.g. golden syrup v. acetone)  *I wanted to know how far from container will they fall?* This is simply governed by projectile motion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Kinematic_quantities_of_projectile_motion) It has nothing to do with fluid mechanics. You really need to separate the two.

Comment: But the projectile motion would be based on exit velocity, is that correct? (That is why liquid from top hole travels less distance than the bottom hole in the Toricelli image in Wikipedia). Would different real life liquids have different exit velocity? Would denisty, for example, matter?

Comment: Yes, projectile motion depends enormously on exit velocity, of course, and thus on viscosity. Different liquids show different exit velocities. E.g. golden syrup would have a much lower exit velocity than water or acetone. Density however doesn't come into it.

Comment: Ah thanks for that explanation. So viscosity will determine which liquid travels greatest distance but density will not. I guess I could ask why density doesn't come into picture but that would be separate question. Thanks!

Comment: Density doesn't 'enter the equation': just see Torricelli: *mass doesn't matter*. This is common to all problems of *free fall*. Viscosity does play a *decelerating* role HERE but has nothing to do with density or mass.

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance vote!